# Не работает привязка из контейнера ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Я использую паттерн MVVM, привязываю ViewModel к DataContext.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
```

В ViewModel у меня есть свойства Width и Height. Которые должны задавать количество столбцов и строк.

```
     public int Width
        {
            get { return Field[0].Count; }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return Field.Count; }
        }
```

**Код XAML(Почти в конце попытка привязаться к свойству)**

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Red" >
            <ItemsControl  Background="#3A4047"  ItemsSource="{Binding Field}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Width="20" Height="20" Margin="1"  >
                                        <!--BorderThickness="1"-->
                                        <Border.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue"/>-->
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Snake">
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Food">
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Border.Style>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <!--<VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>-->
                                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWay}" Columns="{Binding Width, Mode=OneWay}"></UniformGrid>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
```

**В итоге - сбой привязки**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgUdr.png

Field -
   `public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>> Field = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>();`

Comment: `сбой привязки` как вы это поняли? Что такое `Field`? Как тестировали? Нужно больше кода.

Comment: Сверху есть менюшка. Сейчас прикреплю фото и больше информации

Comment: Все элементы внутри коллекции, будут иметь `DataContext` на элемент этой коллекции (в вашем случае `Field`), в котором у вас как бы нету размеров. Если вам надо на уровень выше, то берите предка и привязывайтесь к нему а-ля `{Binding DataContext.Свойство, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ТипПредка}}`. И да, не забывайте, если вы меняете свойство через код, то надо реализовать INPC!

Comment: А и да, привязка в WPF работает **ТОЛЬКО** к **публичным свойствам**, а не полям.

Comment: А что в моем случае является ТипПредка ?

Comment: Ну, наверное ItemsControl

Comment: Когда я поменял VirtualizingStackPanel на UniformGrid, престали работать стили, можете подсказать ка это исправить ?

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>> Field { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>();`